# How can I substract two columns from two tables who share just a foreignKey to another table

Tags: linq

I Have 3 Tables as following:

1. Bank Info

```cs
public class Bank 
{
    [Key]
    public int ID {get; set;}

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Bank Name is required")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string BankName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bank Name is required")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string AccountNo { get; set; }
}
```

2. Expense Details

```cs
public class Expense 
{
    [Key]
    public int ID {get; set;}

    public int SubAccountID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(SubAccountID))]
    public virtual SubAccount SubAccount { get; set; }

    public int MonthID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(MonthID))]
    public virtual Month Month { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReceiptDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Beneficiary")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Beneficiary is required")]
    public string Beneficiary { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ammount is required")]
    public double ReceiptAmount { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    [StringLength(300)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Bank is required")]
    [Display(Name ="Bank")]
    public int BanksID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(BanksID))]
    public virtual Bank Bank { get; set; }
}
```

3. Income Details

```cs
public class IncomeTransaction         
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Bank Info is required")]

    public int BankID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(BankID))]
    public Bank Bank { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Transaction No")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string TransactionNo { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Amount is required")]
    public double Amount { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Transaction Date is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Transaction Date")]
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Income Source is required")]
    [StringLength(100)] 
    [Display(Name ="Income Source")]
    public string IncomeSource { get; set; }
}
```

Also I have a view model to display the bank details and Current Balance

4.Shared BankModel

```cs
public class SharedBank 
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bank Name is required")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string BankName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bank Name is required")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string AccountNo { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public double Balance { get; set; }
}
```

I want to return the Bank Information and Current Balance for each bank.
so far I've tried this :

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<SharedBank>> GetBankBalances()
{
    return await (
        from bank in _pisa.Banks
        join trans in _pisa.IncomeTransactions on bank.ID equals trans.BankID
        join exp in _pisa.Expenses on bank.ID equals exp.BanksID
        group new {trans,exp, bank} by new {trans.BankID, exp.BanksID, bank.ID,bank.BankName,bank.AccountNo} into g
        select new SharedBank()
        {
            ID = g.Key.ID,
            AccountNo = g.Key.AccountNo,
            BankName = g.Key.BankName,
            Balance = g.Sum(o=> o.trans.Amount - o.exp.ReceiptAmount )

        })
    .Distinct()
    .ToListAsync();          
}
```

this query multiplies the incomeAmount by Expense record count, like I've 1 record of amount 2000 in my IncomeTransaction table, also I've 3 records in expense, so this query gives me an income amount of 6000 instead of 2000, I want to get the total expense minus total income for each bank as balance

Please help, how can I achieve this.
thank you very much

```
[Bank Table][1]
```

[IncomeTransactions][2]

```
[Expennses Table][3]
```

[The Page][4]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IHwV.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5lYH.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4aIU.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEvxB.png
```

Comment: I do not see any reason why records are multiplied. You have applied grouping, which should reduce count of returned records. Anyway grouping key can be simplified to`new {bank.ID, bank.BankName, bank.AccountNo}`

Comment: thanks svyatoslav danyliv for the grouping tip, already applied, but the query gives me 6000 instead of 2000, I don't know why?

Comment: Three fields `new {bank.ID, bank.BankName, bank.AccountNo}` in result should be UNIQUE. How many banks do you have?

Comment: two banks, one of them have no income nor expense

Comment: Update question with generated SQL. But it looks like impossible. And Remove `Distinct` please.

Comment: I've updated the post with images from the tables and the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add two navigation properties inside "Bank"

```
    public List<IncomeTransaction> IncomeTransactions { get; set; }
    public List<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
```

Then, instead of using "Join", use "Include":

```
    var result = banks.Include(x=>x.Expenses)
                      .Include(x=>x.IncomeTransactions)
                      .Select(x => new SharedBank
                       {
                         Balance = x.Expenses.Sum(y => y.ReceiptAmount) - x.IncomeTransactions.Sum(x => x.Amount)
                       });
```

Comment: thank you very much shohreh, this is the answer for my question!, it has solved my problem :)

Comment: good! you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add all income and all expenses separately, then subtract the totals to get the final balance. Like so:

```
var bankBalances = banks
    .Join(expenses, 
          b => b.ID, 
          e => e.BanksID, 
          (b, e) => new { Bank = b, Expense = e})
    .Join(transactions, 
          x => x.Bank.ID, 
          t => t.BankID, 
          (x, t) => new { Bank = x.Bank, Expense = x.Expense, Transaction = t })
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Bank.ID, x.Bank.BankName, x.Bank.AccountNo } )
    .Select(x => new SharedBank 
    { 
        ID = x.Key.ID, 
        BankName = x.Key.BankName, 
        AccountNo = x.Key.AccountNo, 
        Balance = x.Sum(t => t.Transaction.Amount) - x.Sum(e => e.Expense.ReceiptAmount)
    });
```

Comment: thanks Carlos for the response, this query gives me balance but multiplied by the income record count, for example I have 3k+2K=5k income and 100+200=300 of expenses, the query gives 9400 instead of 4700, but thanks you pointed the right direction for adding them together and then substracting it

Answer (score 0):

[generated query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4lDV.png)
thanks Carlo Bos for pointing me the right direction.
I couldn't do it with linq query but I've solved my problem with stored procedure:

select ID, BankName,AccountNo
,(select isnull(sum(Amount),0) from IncomeTransactions where BankID=banks.ID)Income
,(select isnull(sum(ReceiptAmount),0) from Expenses where BanksID =banks.ID)Expenses
,(select isnull(sum(Amount),0) from IncomeTransactions where BankID=banks.ID)-
(select isnull(sum(ReceiptAmount),0) from Expenses where BanksID =banks.ID)Balance
from Banks